# How to compile CoreAudio PlayFile sample code for 64 bit?

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, core-audio

This is a newbie CoreAudio question.  I downloaded Apple's [PlayFile sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlayFile/Listings/PlayFile_cpp.html) code.  If I use the provided Xcode project, it builds it as 32 bit, passing `-arch i386` to the compiler.   If I build from the command line and and pass `-arch i386` it still all works fine, but if I remove that flag or change it to `-arch x86_64`, the program dies on `AUOpenGraph` with an error code of -2005 (badComponentType).

How do I compile it as a 64 bit program?  I'd like to know just the flags to pass to `clang` or `gcc`.

Comment: How do you compile in command line. I still have an error even when i include -arch i386. I use Snow Leopard.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember how I was doing this.  All I can suggest is look at the flags in the compile log in Xcode.  I may have been calling `xcodebuild` from the command line.  BTW, why did you remove 32-64-bit tag from the question?  Seems like a relevant tag, no?